# Seleccionar un valor de select y date dependiendo de una consulta MYSQL

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, jquery

tengo el siguiente inconveniente... Estoy desarrollando un apartado donde puedo editar un paciente ya cargado, el problema que tengo son los input de tipo "select", "date" y checkbox.

Tengo la consulta a la base ya creada y puedo mostrar el resultado mediante php y los puedo llevar a js mediante los data attributes de las etiquetas.
En cuestión necesitaria que venga por defecto en el select lo que ya estaba cargado y lo mismo en los otros inputs, dejo el código de los 3 casos:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
 <label class="mt-4 mb-2"  for="inputFechaNacimiento">Fecha de nacimiento</label>
 <input type="date" class="form-control w-75" id="inputFechaNacimiento" name="fechaNacimiento"         data-fechaNacimiento="<?php $newFechaNacimiento ?>">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
 <label class="mt-4 mb-2" for="inputSexo">Sexo</label>
  <select name="sexo" id="inputSexo" class="d-block w-75 p-2">
   <option value="masculino">Masculino</option>
   <option value="femenino">Femenino</option>
   <option value="otro">Otro</option>
 </select>    
</div>

<!-- Acá el select que trae los datos de MYSQL-->

<div class="col-sm-6">
 <label class="mt-4 mb-2"  for="inputObraSocial">Obra social</label>
 <select name="obraSocial" id="inputObrasocial" class="d-block w-75 p-2">
  <?php
  $query = "SELECT * FROM obrassociales";
  $ejecutar = mysqli_query($conexion,$query)or die(mysqli_error($conexion));
                                        
  ?>
  <?php  foreach ($ejecutar as $key => $opciones): ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $opciones['empresa'].$opciones['plan']?>">
    <?php echo $opciones['empresa'] . $opciones['plan']?>
   </option>
  <?php endforeach ?>
 </select>
</div>
```

Acá dejo el codigo de la consulta a la base

```
 include('./php/conexion.php');

    if(isset($_GET['id_paciente'])){
        $idPaciente = $_GET['id_paciente'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM pacientes WHERE id = $idPaciente";
        $queryCon = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
        $paciente= mysqli_fetch_array($queryCon);
```

Comment: @Triby Gracias por comentar, ya edito eso!

Comment: @Triby Como se puede ver en el codigo llamo a la tabla obrassociales y de ahi concateno el nombre de la empresa y el plan medico, lo cual me quedaria guardado en $pacientes['obrasocial'];

Comment: @Triby Hola Triby, sabes que tengo un problema con la primer funcion que me recomendaste, en la parte de los parametros, me indica esto: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: Creo que me estoy acostumbrando a Javascript y omití los `$` al definir las variables de la función.

Comment: @Triby jajaja yo me estaba volviendo loco porque agregue esos $ para definir las variables y sin embargo seguia sin funcionar, ahora con lo que actualziaste anda perfecto, de nuevo muchisimas gracias por tu enorme aporte!!

Comment: @Triby Perdon las molestias ocasionadas pero estoy teniendo complicaciones con el el apartado del select de obras, me indica el siguiente error: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given ... Si cambio el parametro solamente por $ejecutar aparece de error  Trying to access array offset on value y  Undefined variable: opciones

Comment: Cierto, debería ser solo `mysqli_fetch_assoc($ejecutar)`, quitando la conexión.

Comment: @Triby Claro lo reemplacé y ahora tengo los siguientes errores y no puedo solucionarlos :( 1) Undefined variable: opciones y el 2)  Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Comment: Edita la pregunta para agregar el código actualizado. En la respuesta no hay una variable `$opciones`, hay que ver de dónde sale.

Comment: @Triby la variable $opciones esta en la respuesta que escribiste, en el while del fetch assoc: obraOpciones[$opciones['empresa'].$opciones['plan']] = $opciones['empresa'] . $opciones['plan'];

Comment: ¡Diantres, se nota que ando distraído! Solo hay que remplazar `$fila` en el ciclo: `while($opciones = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ejecutar))`

Comment: @Triby Muchas gracias ahora me funciona todo, realmente muchisimas gracias!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este fragmento de código tienes un error:

```
$ejecutar = mysqli_query($conexion,$query)or die(mysqli_error($conexion));
foreach ($ejecutar as $key => $opciones):
    /* ......... */
endforeach;
```

- La variable `$ejecutar` contiene un recurso de acceso a resultados de la consulta
- No puedes recorrerlo, porque no es un arreglo
- Debes leer los resultados, de preferencia con [mysqli_fetch_assoc()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) porque devuelve solo un arreglo asociativo en lugar de arreglo numérico + asociativo, que es lo que devuelve `mysqli_fetch_array()`.

Para facilitar un poco el trabajo, te recomiendo crear una función que llene las opciones de cada desplegable, que va a recibir por parámetros el valor actual y un arreglo de opciones con pares `clave => texto`:

```
function selectOptions($value = '', $options = []) {
    foreach($options as $key => $text) {
        // Si la clave actual es igual al valor, marcar como seleccionado
        $selected = ($key == $value) ? ' selected' : '';
        echo "<option value=\"$key\"$selected>$text</option>";
    }
}
```

Muy sencilla, ¿cierto?... ¿Cómo usarla?

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
 <label class="mt-4 mb-2" for="inputSexo">Sexo</label>
  <select name="sexo" id="inputSexo" class="d-block w-75 p-2">
<?php
    // Llenar opciones
    selectOptions(
        // Primero el valor actual
        $paciente['sexo'],
        // Después arreglo de opciones disponibles
        [
            'masculino' => 'Masculino',
            'femenino' => 'Femenino',
            'otro' => 'Otro'
        ]
    );
?>
 </select>    
</div>
```

"Complicando" un poco las cosas, las opciones provienen de base de datos:

```
<?php
// Primero define el arreglo de opciones
$obraOpciones = [];
// Genera la consulta para llenar el arreglo, solo usa los campos necesarios
$query = "SELECT empresa, plan FROM obrassociales";
$ejecutar = mysqli_query($conexion, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));
// Crea un ciclo para leer los resultados
while($opciones = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ejecutar)) {
    // Llena el arreglo
    $obraOpciones[$opciones['empresa'].$opciones['plan']] = $opciones['empresa'] . $opciones['plan'];
}
// Ya estás listo para crear el desplegable
?>

<div class="col-sm-6">
 <label class="mt-4 mb-2"  for="inputObraSocial">Obra social</label>
 <select name="obraSocial" id="inputObrasocial" class="d-block w-75 p-2">
<?php
    selectOptions($paciente['obraSocial'], $obraOpciones);
?>
 </select>
</div>
```

Para otros campos (texto, fecha, número, etc.) solo necesitas mostrar el valor actual en el atributo `value`:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
 <label class="mt-4 mb-2"  for="inputFechaNacimiento">Fecha de nacimiento</label>
 <input type="date" class="form-control w-75" id="inputFechaNacimiento" name="fechaNacimiento" data-fechaNacimiento="<?php echo $paciente['fechaNacimiento']; ?>" value=""<?php echo $paciente['fechaNacimiento']; ?>"">
</div>
```

Finalmente, para *checkbox* solo hay que saber si está marcado o no, pero depende de cómo almacenas los valores en base de datos, yo suelo usar 1 si debe estar marcado y cero cuando no:

```
<?php
// Saber si debe estar marcado o no
$checked = ($paciente['nombreDeCampo'] == 1) ? ' checked': '';
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="nombreDeCampo" value="1"<?php echo $checked; ?>>
```

Para determinar si una opción de desplegable debe marcarse como seleccionada o si un *checkbox* debe aparecer marcado estoy usando [asignación ternaria](https://www.neoguias.com/if-abreviado-en-php-el-operador-ternario/).

No olvides revisar los nombres de columnas que corresponden a `$paciente` para cada elemento del formulario.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu tiempo a resolver mi problema! me sirvió todo lo que me propusiste.

Comment: @LeonelGabrielWetzel, actualicé la función, faltaban algunos `$` en variables.